# Count occurrences of role across users?

Tags: abap, opensql

The table I use stores different system names, corresponding users and their role.
My target is to use the *SELECT* and *COUNT* commands together to get some output like this:

```
SysName | Role1 | Role2 | Role3
----------------------------------
sys1    | 10    | 5     | 25
sys2    | 0     | 70    | 12
```

But it seems that some of the SQL commands or their structure doesn´t work in ABAP code.

Could you let me know if something like this is possible and when how?

Comment: ABAP is space sensitive. Did you use a space between COUNT and its parentheses?

Comment: Show us the structure of your table

Comment: I think it isnt a syntax error.

The columns are:
- system name
- user name
- role type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was triggered because the key word "DISTINCT" was missing

The correct answer should be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT col1 ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With this Command you are able to count everything in a Table. Just add your WHERE conditions:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) INTO integer FROM table [WHERE...].
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Select col1, COUNT( col2 ) INTO TABLE @tbl GROUP BY col1 doesn't work in abap, only Select col1, COUNT( DISTINCT col2 ) INTO TABLE @tbl GROUP BY col1. I think You should use Select + Loop in this case

Comment: It's not true. `SELECT COUNT` perfectly works standalone.

Comment: Sorry for unclear answer. I want to say that this type of select doesn't work in abap. SELECT col1 , COUNT( col2 ) INTO TABLE @tbl GROUP BY col1.